# on Drupal with store locator on root of two location

Tags: drupal

Some please give me solution.

I am working on Drupal with location module and gmap module. I need to create a store search with two options, one is based on particular location and another option is based on root search, that is if user gives two location ( From and To) it needs to search the stores what are all locate in the path of those two location. eg: http://www.freightlinertrucks.com/Dealers/?routeStart=OREGON&routeEnd=NEVADA#filters=&south=38.34882726120935&west=-127.374750859375&north=44.90905399459999&east=-109.906489140625

I could get the 1st option using Location filter and I need solution for the root search with the same location module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In views you could use hook_form_alter to add or edit exposed filters to add the to and from locations.

Then use hook_views_query_alter to search for any stores with a bounding box of the two and from locations.

Comment: I got the fields and the address marked on the gmap, but struggling to get the path on the map which I have already and to get the store locations which occurred on the path of two locations.